# CSS3 & HTML5 - Rotating group of objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project in which I have a draggable objects.
After I place those object I want to create a "camera view" in which I can change the angle of view. (form 2d to 3d)

I'm trying all kinds of combinations (CSS3-rotate3d, HTML5-canvas)
or maybe JavaScript.

Is anybody knows what is the best way to build the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript to drive a CSS3 rotate3d transform is probably your best bet, as in [this demo](http://sandropaganotti.com/2010/09/09/a-mouse-driven-css3-rotate3d-parallax-gallery-for-safari/).

Using canvas would require somehow re-drawing your draggable items in the canvas, which may be easy, or extremely difficult, depending on what they are.  If they are all images, drawing them into the canvas and [rotating](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1253) them with WebGL would be doable.  Drawing arbitrary DOM elements into a canvas is probably extremely difficult.

The rotate3d CSS3 transform is probably easier to implement, but I suspect it has less support than WebGL.  rotate3d works in at least Chrome and Safari, but WebGL has pretty slim support as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks,every advise is usefull :-)